# Best way of sharing information between users on the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I have recently made my first iPhone app and plan on making another one. For my next app I want users to easily be able to find other iPhone users and then share the information on the app, will be an array of data or something similar.

I can use a webserver to communicate with every user, but I feel that it would be faster to simply share everything directly between users. is there a way to do this?

I also need to make the information secure, users should only be able to share/get information between users that have approved each other.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with a client-server service you should use the [Restkit framework](http://restkit.org/). It implements RestFull for iPhone, and you can create a web service with a php framework like symphony at the server side. This two frameworks will make the solution easy on each side of the service.

For secure the connection https is the easiest way. For the permission matter you should code it in the server. A RestFull request should return the information a user have permission to see, identify the users could be done with a user/password, token or if you want to identify them by the device you could use [openUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID).

I hope this give you some clues to solve the problem!